# Filtering fields with duplicates in django

Tags: python, django

Guys am trying to filter duplicates in a field in  my model

for Example my models are:

```
class Household(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(
        Office,
        related_name='households',
        help_text=_('The office that manages this data'),
    )

    uuid = UUIDField(
        auto=True,
        version=4,
        help_text=_('Unique identifier for each household'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        _('Family Name'),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_('Name by which the household goes by'),
        db_index=True

class Person(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True, version=4, help_text=_('unique id'))

    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last name"), max_length=255, help_text=_('last name'), db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, help_text=_('first name'))
    middle_name = models.CharField(_("Middle name"), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, help_text=_('middle name'))
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, verbose_name=_('Location'), help_text=_('location'))
 household = models.ForeignKey(
        Household,
        related_name='active_or_inactive_members',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_("Household"),
        help_text=_('Household')
    )
```

am using this query to get all duplicate persons in a household:

first am filtering all households in an office

```
households = Household.objects.filter(office='so-co')
```

then  i iterate over this households to filter persons with duplicate ids

```
for household in households:
    persons = Person.objects.values('last_name').annotate(Count('id')).order_by().filter(id__count__gt=1)
    for person in persons:
        print person
```

The problem is that my queryset is printing all persons, what am i missing out here?

Comment: Try this: `persons=set(household.active_or_inactive_members.values_list('last_name'))`

Answer (score 0):

You are not filtering on `household` in the for loop. You might get the `Persons` related to a household using the `related_name`:

```
persons = household.active_or_inactive_members.all()
```

To find duplicates on `last_name`:

```
persons = household.active_or_inactive_members.values('last_name')...... # your code here
```